# Video not playing from typescript in owl carosal only sound is playing , video screen not moving

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, owl-carousel

I have updated my previous question.  I am trying to play a video in Owl Carousal using on button click but it's not working properly. Some of the videos are playing but most of the time it's not.  Without carousal normally for a single video, it's working fine, is any CSS related to owl carousal creating an issue?  I am getting proper video elements in the console too.  The video seems to be playing and can hear the video sound it's not playing video seems to video screen stuck

Here is my HTML :

I am trying to create a play button by clicking with the function playVideo()

```
 <div class="big_img mediaCursor" *ngIf="post.mediaData && post.mediaData.length > 1 && post.post_type == 'is_post'" >
        <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions1"  #owlCarousel (change)="handleSlide($event)">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let img of post.mediaData"  >
            <ng-template class="slide"  carouselSlide>
              <button  *ngIf="img.media_type === 'video'" class="btn-play-video" id="video_play_{{img.id}}" (click)="playVideo(img.id)">
                <i class="ti ti-control-play"></i>Play
              </button>
              <div class="mb-0 testtts" id="parentVideo_{{img.id}}" >
                <img *ngIf="img.media_type === 'image'" (click)="Openpost(post.post_id)" [src]="img.file_path" alt="Icelandic"
                  class="big_img img-fluid cursor"  />
                  <video id="video_{{img.id}}" width="640"  controls preload="none"    poster="{{img.video_thumb}}"
                    *ngIf="img.media_type === 'video'" class="video-js vjs-default-skin cursor"
                    >
                    <source src="{{ img.file_path }}#t=1" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </ng-container>
        </owl-carousel-o>
      </div>
```

Here is my TS for the function playVideo() :

```
  playVideo(eleId){
   let button:HTMLButtonElement = document.querySelector('#video_play_' + eleId)
   let video:HTMLVideoElement =  document.querySelector('#video_' + eleId)
   let parentDiv:HTMLDivElement = document.querySelector('#parentVideo_' + eleId)
   let ddVHeight = parentDiv.offsetHeight
   video.load();
  video.onloadeddata = (event) => {
    video.play()
   this.renderer.setStyle(parentDiv, "height", `${ddVHeight}px`);
    this.renderer.listen(video, 'playing', () => {
     this.renderer.addClass(button, 'hide');
   })
   this.renderer.listen(video, 'pause', () => {
     this.renderer.removeClass(button, 'hide');
   })
    
};

  }
```

Any suggestion or hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your browsers autoplay policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue myself. Generally, it is found that direct owl carousal does not allow playing video by doing just video. play() for video element.

So, I tried to take a video element based on the owl carousel class owl-item. Need to assign an ID for the owl carousel present in page. I have multiple carousals in a single page and it gets incremented whenever API gets called.

TS:

```
 playVideo2(ele:any) {
    let cc:any = '.owl-' + ele + ' .owl-item.active video'
    if (this.owlCarousel) {
      const videoElement = document.querySelector(cc) as HTMLVideoElement | null;
      if (videoElement) {
        videoElement.play(); 
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="big_img mediaCursor owl-{{post.post_id}}" *ngIf="post.mediaData && post.mediaData.length > 1 && post.post_type == 'is_post'" >
        <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions1"  #owlCarousel (change)="handleSlide($event)">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let img of post.mediaData"  >
            <ng-template class="slide"  carouselSlide>
              <button  *ngIf="img.media_type === 'video'" class="btn-play-video" id="video_play_{{img.id}}" (click)="playVideo2(post.post_id)">
                <i class="ti ti-control-play"></i>Play
              </button>
              <div class="mb-0 testtts" id="parentVideo_{{img.id}}" >
                <img *ngIf="img.media_type === 'image'" (click)="Openpost(post.post_id)" [src]="img.file_path" alt="Icelandic"
                  class="big_img img-fluid cursor"  />
                  <video id="video_{{img.id}}" width="640" height=""  controls preload="metadata"    poster="{{img.video_thumb}}"
                    *ngIf="img.media_type === 'video'" class="video-js vjs-default-skin cursor"
                    >
                    <source src="{{ img.file_path }}#t=1" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </ng-container>
        </owl-carousel-o>
      </div>
```

Hope it will be helpful for anyone looking to implement same.

Answer (score 0):

you should not store conditions into your table 
need to store data like

$workshop_sales and  1600000  in seporate columns

then you can make condition

like something

```
if($row10["open_condition"] > $row10["open_condition_value"]){
//your code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `video.play()` to outside of `onloadeddata` and you don't need `video.load()`

`video.play()` return a promise, check if there is a error there?
`video.play().then(console.log).catch(console.log)`
check dev tools console for errors?
what browser are you testing on?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have checked already that way but it was not working.

Comment: updated the answer @chgav007

Comment: Hello, I have checked with video. play().then(console. log).catch(console.log) but there are no errors showing video. play() is working but only the sound is playing not properly video as it should work. I have checked on chrome as well as on firefox. video screen not moving.